# How to wrap items in flexbox for smaller screens?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to create a layout for different resize. I need to reach the result in these images here:

[image: flexbox result]

I have this code:

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.item {
  background-color: black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  flex: 2;
  color: #fff;
}
.item:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: grey;
  flex: 1
}
.item:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 0.5;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 990px) {
  .container {
    height: auto;
    display: table;
  }
  .item:nth-child(2) {
    float: left;
  }
  .item:nth-child(3) {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <h2>title1</h2>
    <hr>You'll notice that even though this column has far more content in it, instead of the other columns ending early, they size themselves to meet the end of this column vertically.</div>
  <div class="item">
    <h2>title2</h2>
    <hr>Normally, the only way to achieve this would be either a hack, or to set all boxes to min-height.
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h2>title3</h2>
    <hr>This is a column with not much content.
  </div>
</section>
```

Here there's a codepen https://codepen.io/darudev/pen/pyBrzL

Problem is in 990px resize view, I don't find solution to create the same view as "mockup".

Is there someone that can help me or give me some suggestions?

Thank you.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You don't need the table and float properties in your code.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 990px) {
  .container {
    height: auto;
    display: table;
  }
  .item:nth-child(2) {
    float: left;
  }
  .item:nth-child(3) {
    float: right;
  }
}
```

The entire layout can be made with flexbox.

*Here's the solution:* When the screen resizes smaller than 990px, allow flex items to wrap and give the first item a 100% width, which forces the following items to the next line.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  background-color: black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 20px;
  flex: 2;
  color: #fff;
}

.item:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: grey;
  flex: 1;
}

.item:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: green;
  flex: 0.5;
}

@media screen and (max-width:990px) {
  .container { flex-wrap: wrap;  }
  .item:first-child { flex-basis: 100%; }
}
```

```html
<section class="container">
  <div class="item">
    <h2>title1</h2>
    <hr>You'll notice that even though this column has far more content in it, 
         instead of the other columns ending early, they size themselves to meet the end
         of this column vertically.</div>
  <div class="item">
    <h2>title2</h2>
    <hr>Normally, the only way to achieve this would be either a hack, or to set
        all boxes to min-height.</div>
  <div class="item">
    <h2>title3</h2>
    <hr>This is a column with not much content.
  </div>
</section>
```

[**revised codepen**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wGZqpy?editors=1100)

Comment: I think that you can achieve this without media queries by just setting the min-width of .item:first-child.